# Inconsistencies in "MSIE" Trident versioning in User Agent

Tags: internet-explorer, user-agent

I am working on a project that activates a set of CSS/Javascript features according to the engine version of the browser provided in the User Agent.

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)
```

[As we know it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29#Versions), **Trident 6.0** is only available in MSIE 10. I don't understand how an old MSIE 7.0 User Agent contains this versioning information.

What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's IE10 in *Compatibility View* mode;

> When a webpage is displayed in Compatibility View, Internet Explorer
>   10 displays the page in IE7 Standards mode, which is consistent with
>   the behavior of Internet Explorer 9 and Windows Internet Explorer 8.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I suppose I should treat **Trident/6.0** as MSIE 10.0, regardless if it is in Compatibility View mode, is that correct?

Comment: Well presumably its in compatibility view because IE10/Trident 6 don't like the page for some reason so I would pay attention to the fact it wants to be treated like IE 7

Comment: You're right. I've included IE exceptions respecting compatibility view. Thanks